# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

In the following code, I get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const util = require('util');

async function getDB() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./project.db', (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        reject(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Connected to the project database.');
        resolve(db)
      }
    });
    return db
  });
}


try {
  // run these statements once to set up the db
  let db = getDB();
  db.run(`CREATE TABLE services(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, service text, date text)`);
  db.run(`INSERT INTO services(id, service, date) VALUES (1, 'blah', '01-23-1987')`)
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}


const db = getDB();
const dbGetAsync = util.promisify(db.get);

exports.get = async function(service) {

  let sql = `SELECT Id id,
    Service service,
    Date date
    FROM services
    WHERE service  = ?`;

  const row = await dbGetAsync(sql, [service], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      reject(err)
    }
    let this_row = {'row': row.id, 'service': row.service};
    this_row ? console.log(row.id, row.service, row.date) : console.log(`No service found with the name ${service}`);
    resolve(this_row)
  });

  return row;
}

let row = exports.get('blah')
```

It says the problem is in line 31: `const dbGetAsync = util.promisify(db.get);`

```
$ mocha src/tests/testStates.js
C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
        at Object.promisify (internal/util.js:256:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cody\Projects\goggle-indexer\src\state.js:32:25)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cody\Projects\goggle-indexer\src\tests\testStates.js:7:15)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:330:36
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:327:14)
        at Mocha.run (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:804:10)
        at Object.exports.singleRun (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:207:16)
        at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:300:13)
        at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:296:3)
        at Object.runCommand (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
        at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
        at Object.parse (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
        at Object.exports.main (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:63:6)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cody\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:10:23)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I'm having problems using this promisify library.

Comment: `db` appears to be a Promise, since `getDB` returns a Promise, right? Promises don't have a `get` method, so I'd expect `db.get` to be `undefined`. I suspect you really want to do `getDB().then(db=>{ ... })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all no need to use `return db;` inside **new Promise()** because it is not expecting any return value from the callback function.

Since getDB() is an asynchronous function, it needs to be used with `await` keyword to get the value or will be available in handler function of `.then`.

It doesn't make sense to me that you are calling `getDB()` multiple times.

It is better to read if instead of directly assigning an anonymous function to exports object key like this `exports.get = async function()` and then use it from exports object for use in same file, it would be better to define a named get function and then use it as well as export it.

You are using reject and resolve keywords outside **new promise()** constructor which is not possible.

I have rewritten your code, I am not sure if I have missed anything, but do take a look and please inform if you are still facing any issues.

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const util = require("util");

async function getDB() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database("./project.db", err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Connected to the project database.");
        resolve(db);
      }
    });
  });
}

try {
  // run these statements once to set up the db
  let db = await getDB();
  db.run(
    `CREATE TABLE services(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, service text, date text)`
  );
  db.run(
    `INSERT INTO services(id, service, date) VALUES (1, 'blah', '01-23-1987')`
  );
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

const db = await getDB();
const dbGetAsync = util.promisify(db.get);

async function get(service) {
  let sql = `SELECT Id id, Service service, Date date FROM services WHERE service  = ?`;

  try {
    const row = await dbGetAsync(sql, [service]);
    let this_row = { row: row.id, service: row.service };
    this_row
      ? console.log(row.id, row.service, row.date)
      : console.log(`No service found with the name ${service}`);
    return row;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}

let row = await get("blah");

exports.get = get;
```

Answer (score 20):

I got this error because I was using an old Node version (8.17.0), updating Node to a newer version (12.14.0) fixed this error.

Answer (score 8):

getDB is an async function returning a Promise, so you have to `await` for the promise to resolve or chain a `then` to use its returned value:

```js
// you have to put it inside an async function
const db = await getDB();
const dbGetAsync = util.promisify(db.get);
```

```js
getDB().then(function(db){
  return util.promisify(db.get);
}).then(function(getFunction){
  // use get
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `await` before getDB() as it is return promise, so that is why you are getting error. see the correction below:

```
const db = await getDB();
const dbGetAsync = util.promisify(db.get);
```

Also you have to wrap await inside async function other it won't work like this:

```
(async function(){
  let bar = await foo();
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE is internal Node.js error. It means that your code may invoke build-int function with wrong arguments.

I've faced same error (ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE) but with much simpler code and in different circumstances.

```
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const readDirAsync = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
```

Reason was that fs.readFile and fs.readdir were both undefined. If you call util.promisify with undefined then Node.js produce a error ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE.

In my case reason was that unit test was mocking build-in fs module and some of dependencies were initialized with 2 lines of code above.